# keep failing to send values to PHP with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

code lovers!

i want to send a value of input box to PHP and check the value on the PHP file. when the page is loaded. but i keep failing no matter what i try in various ways.

basically i want to send the value of this input box to PHP.

```
Current Counte : <input type="text" name="currentCount" id="currentCount" value="6">
<span> result </span>
```

and these are what i have tried so far but nothing really worked.

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var currentCount = $("#currentCount").val();
    console.log(currentCount);
     $.post("counteSever.php", {currentCount2: currentCount}, 
        function(result){
        $("span").html(result);
         });
      });

</script>
```

Second One

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var currentCount = $("#currentCount").val();
    console.log(currentCount);
   $.ajax({
    url: 'counteSever.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {"currentCount2": currentCount},
    dataType: 'JSON',
})
.done(function() {
    console.log(currentCount + " Done");
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
})
.always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
});

});
</script>
```

and Third one

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'counteSever.php',
    data : { "currentCount2" : currentCount},
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(response){
        $('span').text(name);
        alert(response.data);
    }
});
```

and my simple PHP file to check if the value is sent or not.

```
<?php

$current = $_POST['currentCount2'];

echo $current;

?>
```

Seriously don't know what's the problem, i don't have any problem to check the value on client-side, but  it doesn't seem to send the value to PHP cos i keep having "Undefined index: currentCount2 " error. 
if i don't have any problem with the ajax function? Thanks!

Comment: All of your attempts seem fine. Have you checked in the console to see if there's any errors, and also to see what the response code from the request is?

Comment: Also, it seems a little redundant to make an AJAX request when the page loads - you already know the state of the page at the point anyway...? I assume this is just a learning exercise?

Comment: You get the value of the input as soon as the document is loaded. You should not do this. An input is meant for.... manual input, which takes time. So get the value when the form, of which the input is a part, is submitted by the user.

Comment: @james David Deann do you want to display data through ajax like this [shown in this image ](https://ibb.co/nOcK3F)

Comment: Checkout inspect element, tab network, press F5 and check ajax call there. Is it posting good?

Answer (score 0):

As i understood your question you want to send the value of `input field` to `PHP` file and receive it back and display in `<span>` tag.

So here are few minor changes you need to make. see my example below.

IN AJAX SUCCESS FUNCTION ,you can use these 3 ways to bind result to the `<span>` tag
1)`$('span').text(response);`
2)`$('span').append(response);`
3) $('span').html(response);

You will know the difference between them when to use those in these example

This is HTML file

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    Current Counte : <input type="text" name="currentCount" id="currentCount" value="6">
    <br>
    <span> result </span>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var currentCount = $("#currentCount").val();

   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'counteSever.php',
        dataType:'json',
        data : {currentCount2 : currentCount},
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            $('span').append(response);
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is php File counteSever.php

```
<?php
$current = $_POST['currentCount2'];

echo $current;

?>
```

And here is the result image :

[image: Output image]

Comment: Thank you for helping! it works well in client, i can check it's sending value well to PHP, but i don't know why i keep having Undefined index error in PHP.

Comment: @James David Deann can to send me a screen shot of both error and the code

Answer (score -1):

@james, Put the ajax code in bottom of your html file. You r using document.ready(). It will work:)